# Same Etags for different users from different machines

Tags: caching, azure, etag, diskcache

If two users try's to access same **Url** of a site which is being hosted in windows azure from two different machines and as result if they both get **same ETag**. Does that mean cache is being implemented on the web server ?
I am thinking that if cache is not implemented on the disk(server), each user must get a **unique ETag** right ?

Please put me in some proper direction here..